# Why are animals devil fruits not Paramecia?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, why are Zoans not considered Paramecia?

And why is the Mochi Mochi no Mi not just a normal Paramecia because it does not fit in Logia?

Answer (score 3):

Because that is simply how they are defined?
Zoan fruits give the specific ability

> to transform into an animal, as well as transform into a hybrid form of their own species and the species the fruit allows them to transform into.

[Wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Types_of_Devil_Fruit)

Paramecia on the other hand are simply defined as all those powers that are not animal transformation or elemental transformation.

Why the Mochi Mochi no Mi is classified as (special) Paramecia and not Logia is currently unclear.
It was actually first stated to be a Logia.

> In the Magazine release of the chapter, it was stated to be a Logia, but retconned in the Volume release as a "special Paramecia".

[Wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_863#Chapter_Notes)

Functionally it is basically the same as a Logia. A possible explanation for the different classification could be that Mochi is manmade and not a natural element.